# Test server side git-hooks in --dry-run mode

Tags: git, continuous-integration, githooks

We enabled server-side git hooks to enforce GIT based integration policy where we check for commit message format that is pushed. When 'git push' is invoked in the --dry-run mode, the git hooks are not invoked. How can I test the git hooks without actually pushing the code into the repository?

Answer (score 2):

You can either have a test repo on the server side, for you to push.

But for a true *local* test, you might want to use a [client-side `commit-msg` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks), where your commit message validation function can be tested.
That supposes said function can be externalized in its own script, in order to be called from:

- the local client-side `commit-msg` hook
- the server-side `pre-receive` hook